# Crash on textfield become first responder with pickerview

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

so I've been trying to get this pickerview working but I just can't get it to work. When I run the app it crashes without any stacktrace and shows Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [textField becomeFirstResponder]. The pickerArray is correct, so that's not the problem.

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "FindClasses.h"

@interface TestViewController ()
@property UIPickerView *picker;
@property NSArray *pickerArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FindClasses *finder;
@end

@implementation TestViewController

@synthesize finder = _finder;

- (FindClasses *)finder
{
    if (!_finder) _finder = [[FindClasses alloc] init];
    return _finder;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerArray = [self.finder findClassesInTimetable];

    self.classField.delegate = self;
    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.classField.inputView = self.picker;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  {
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView method implementation

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return self.pickerArray.count;
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove `[textField becomeFirstResponder];` from - `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate method

Comment: @SweetAngel I did that and it doesn't crash anymore but there's also no pickerview being shown. Any ideas why?

Comment: Bcoz, by default this delegate automatically set responder to the respective `UITextField`.

Comment: Do you just want to show up the pickerView when the user taps on the textField?

Comment: @GenieWanted Yes exactly

Comment: So, you can popup your pickerView instead of the standard `UIKeyboard` when the user taps on the textField. For this, you will need to set your pickerView as the inputview. Simply like:

    [textfield setInputView:self.picker];

Comment: @GenieWanted Yes, that's what I did in viewDidLoad, but it still doesn't show up when I press on the textfield

Comment: How have you created your classField textField? If you have created your self.classField through Xib, make sure it's connected properly with IBOutlet.

Comment: @GenieWanted yeah it's created in a storyboard, just checked it's linked properly. I added a toolbar to the pickerview which gets shown when I tap on the textfield but the pickerview doesn't appear

Comment: What do you mean "pickerview doesn't appear"? Does the toolbar get shown up on top of an empty area (where the picker is supposed to be shown)? Any screenshots, perhaps?

Comment: @GenieWanted http://i.imgur.com/8Ujv1sq.png This is what I see after the textfield gets pressed

Comment: Seems different.. try commenting the  line   self.classField.inputView = self.picker; and see if that triggers standard UIKeyboard. If it does, then probably, the issue must be with pickerView.

Comment: @GenieWanted no UIKeyboard, the same thing as in the screenshot :(

Comment: Have you modified your textField delegate methods? Set return No anywhere?

Comment: @GenieWanted no I haven't, I'm using xcode 6 and ios 8, is the problem there?

Comment: No. THat shouldn't be the problem. I tried reproducing this issue on my computer and have no issues.. Seems strange..

Comment: @GenieWanted I just tried that as well and it's the same result as before

Comment: @GenieWanted I just reset the iOS simulator and now it works..Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ooooofff!!! :D Finally..

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `[textField becomeFirstResponder];` from the following method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField  {
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

The error is not relating to the picker field. The `becomeFirstResponder` is called automatically when the text field is selected. So there is no need for it to be called here as it would have already been called when you clicked the text field.

Basically your telling the text field that is active, to become active... Give it a go and let me know what the result is.

---

In relation to the picker view not showing up, make sure you have the IBOutlets connected up properly if using storyboards, also edit the following at the top of you .m file so it looks like the below:

Before:

```
@interface TestViewController ()
```

After:

```
@interface TestViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but the pickerView is not shown and that;s where I'm stuck at right now

Comment: Can you update your question to show your .h file please?

Make sure you have your IBOutlets connected properly, also I want to ensure you have set the <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDataSource> in your .h file as they are not specified in the .m file above.

Answer (score 1):

to have ur pickerview as your first responder, use

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

     if([textField isEqual:classField]) {

        [textField setInputView:picker]; //edited ones
        [picker becomeFirstResponder];

        }
    }
```

use this method,
it will help you.

Comment: I added a toolbar, which gets shown but the pickerView still doesn't get shown when I click the textfield

Comment: have u initialised ur picker if not do it `picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];`

Comment: are u using pickerview delegates

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([self.classField isEditing]) {
        [self.picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; //This is not necessary but I prefer it for my purpose
        [self.picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
}
```

**And Make sure your TextField Delegate is calling ... Means `<UITextFieldDelegate>` must be in your .h file like `<UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>`
Hope This Helps You...**

If this doesn't work then Try this

```
    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.picker setDataSource:self];
    [self.picker setDelegate:self];
    [self.classField setInputView:self.picker]
```